# mongoose .save() doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have those code running try to ***save an object*** into **MongoDB**.

The `.save()` never got success run. the code running fine.

`.save()` method **doesn't work**.

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoUrl, {auth: {authdb: "admin"}});
conn.on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
});
conn.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log("connected to " + mongoUrl);
    var cacheSchema = mongoose.Schema({}, {strict: false});
    cacheSchema.set('collection', 'caches');
    // you need to specify which connection is uing.
    var Cache = conn.model('cache', cacheSchema);
    var measure = new Cache();
    measure['test'] = "test";
    measure.save(function(err){
        console.log('test');
    });
});
```

Comment: `the .save() never got success run` How can you tell? you didn't give it a  callback.

Comment: What's wrong? post the error

Comment: I edited the callback. I put the break point at console.log(). it never stopped there

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just ran into a similar issue in my code. For mine, I was dealing with an object within my user document. I had to run a `user.markModified('object')` before the `user.save()` to ensure the changes were saved to the database.
My running theory is that Mongoose wasn't tracking items unset or removed from the database automatically

Comment: Nested objects in a collection need this trick. Works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Please read [this part](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)  of documentation from mongoose and try the following:

```
   var measure = new Cache({test:'teste'}); 
   // or measure.set('test', 'teste');
   measure.save(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
```

You will be able to see the issue if there's any.

Update the issue is using:

```
var Cache = conn.model('cache', cacheSchema);
```

instead of

```
var Cache = mongoose.model('cache', cacheSchema);
```

Comment: I did this, and I'm not able to reach to this line: console.log(err)

Comment: I put break point at console.log(err); it never reach there. the program didn't quit neither. It looks like it's running forever.

Comment: are you sure open event is being triggered?

Comment: Yes, because if I put break point at  measure.save(function(err){,  program stops there. @KevinB

Comment: have you then tried following it function by function to see when it leaves that, and if any future callbacks get called after the stack clears?

Comment: @KevinB   Yes, I put break point at measure.save(function(err){,  then I step into the function,  the next line it stops is at }); which is out of .save()

Comment: @sh977218 can you try var measure = new Cache({test: 'test'});

Comment: @AlvaroJoao I tried this and it's the same.  that's very wired. :(

Comment: I found the issue, var Cache = conn.model('cache', cacheSchema); instead of var Cache = mongoose.model('cache', cacheSchema);

Comment: @sh977218 you can update the answer and mark it as correct answer

Comment: @sh977218 your edits in the question make this question really confusing. I mean your question says the code doesn't save, but then once you've found the solution you've corrected the code. Also your edits on the answer saying "the problem is x instead of y" is confusing too...

The question should show the problem, and the answer should show the correct code.. 

Also maybe link to the [multiple connections](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections) section in the docs.