# Node/Mongoose: Synchronous Find/Save/Delete between Collections: collection1.find(collection2.save(collection1.remove()))

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a database of users and I want to implement deleting a user from one collection (Users).  But before that user is deleted, I wanted to save it to another collection for backup/tracking (DeletedUsers).

So the sequence should be:
1) Find user, 2) save user to DeletedUsers, 3) delete user from Users.

Because this needs to be synchronous, I've nested the functions and sequenced through callbacks.  The problem is the save to DeletedUsers is not working.

Standalone, the save to DeletedUsers works, just not when it's nested in the User.find().

I have setup two different Schemas for the Users/Deleted Users:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({data}));
var DeletedUser = mongoose.model('DeletedUser', new Schema({data}));
```

**Implementation of the delete:**

```
exports.postDeleteUser = function(req,res) {

    var conditions = { '_id': req.params.user_id };

    // Create the new deletedUser object to add to
    // the DeletedUsers collection 
    var deletedUser = new DeletedUser();

    User.findOne(conditions, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {console.error(err);
        } else {
            // Copy over data to the new deletedUser object    
            for (prop in user) {deletedUser[prop] = user[prop];}

            // This is where I save the deletedUser to the
            // new collection.
            // ** This is not executing ** //
            deletedUser.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);    
                    renderViewUser(user['_id'], 0, req, res);

                } else {

                    // However, this delete from Users *is* working
                    User.find(conditions).remove(function() {
                        res.redirect('/');

                    });
                };
            });
        };
    });
};
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may want to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913273/mongoose-save-doesnt-work

Comment: Thanks, I've added `deletedUser.markModified('object');` but it has no effect. Still not saving to the new collection

Comment: When you copy all properties from `user` to `deletedUser`, `_id` will also be copied. Can you try removing that?

Comment: Cool thanks. Actually I just copied over just the fields I needed.  There are some properties other than _id that are also preventing the copy to the new database

Answer (score 1):

As @RaR pointed out, there are some *hidden* properties that are keeping the new data object from saving to the new collection, not just `_id`.

Copying all properties does not work:

```
for (prop in user) {deletedUser[prop] = user[prop];}
```

Only specific properties must deliberately copied:

```
var properties = ['prop1', 'prop2'....];

properties.forEach(function(i) {
    deletedUser[i] = user[i];
});
```